# jQuery: How do you preload sound?

Tags: jquery, audio, preload

I have a website that plays sound when you click a button.

This is how I do it

```
function PlaySound(soundfile) {
    $('#soundContainer').html("<embed src='/uploads/sounds/" + soundfile + "' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>");
}
```

How do you preload the sound file beforehand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just thinking in the top of my head, can you make an ajax request for the sound file, but dont show the button until file is 100% loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "soundfile.mp3",
        success: function() {
            $("#play_button").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a fine solution but not working in IE at least not with sound files, because IE is not able to handle binary files correctly and does not trigger the success function, see this issue for further information: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11426 - discovered it just today.

Answer (score 5):

Do this in HTML5 like this:

```
my_sound = $("<audio>", {src:"filename.mp3",preload:"auto"}).appendTo("body");
```

Then to play it:

```
my_sound[0].play();
```

Answer (score 2):

There are so many better ways to play sound with JavaScript. For my favorite, check out [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). With it, you can simply call `soundManager.load` to load the sound file preemptively.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an AJAX request to it. If your server issues proper caching headers (like *Expires*) it will be stored in the browser cache.
2. The ugly way:

```
soundfile = new Image(); 
soundfile.src = /uploads/sounds/" + soundfile;
```

Comment: Thanks Sanmai, but I don't think the code works... It seems to download the file when the page is loaded, but redownload it when I click the button.

Comment: Did you check for the caching headers? If there is none of them, a client will surely re-download a file. If you're using Apache, take some time and read about **mod_exires**. If not, Google is to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `<embed>`.

You could use an [HTML5 `<audio>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#audio) element without `autoplay`, and later make it start playing with its `play()` method.

Comment: And also sacrifice IE support.

Comment: You can add IE compatibility using <bgsound src="yourmusicfile.mid">.  I'd link some examples, but GeoCities is closed.