# jquery on event make sound

Tags: jquery, audio

I want to know what is the most optimized and speed efficant way of playing a onevent sound (which will be repeated several if not 100's of times). Obv. adding a embed html code does not work as that would cause it to add and delete an embed html code 100's of times causing slowness or even crash.

What other methods are available for repeative sound?

Comment: Some help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762865/jquery-how-do-you-preload-sound

Comment: Obviously you would want to preload the sound file.

Comment: Preloading is for preloading the sound, it doesn't refresh it. SoundManager is extremely bulky and I ultimately only need to play a single file over and over, I don't need 95% of the functions in it.

Comment: How does your EMBED code look like? Which attributes do you set? Are you manipulating the EMBED element programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way this time is still the use of a flash-player which can interact with javascript, so you don't need to embed a sound-file a couple of times, you simply can play the sound if you want to.

If some day  HTML5 is supported enough by all browsers, it would be easier using the `<audio>`-element and its play/pause methods.