# jquery buffer entire audio file and ready to play it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

**Basic Question**
Is there any webpage audio player that will buffer (download) the entire audio file as soon as the page loads and will do this with multiple audio files on one page?

**More information**
I am running a live stage show using a web app that I built. Some of the performers have an audio track that they want to be played during their act (eg: music for a magic act).

The guy in the sound booth cueing the music currently has my web app in front of him (just a `jQuery PHP` webpage) so that he can see the running order of acts. And before the show, he needs to go through his email and download any audio tracks that have been sent to him. So, he's playing tracks in quick time, then jumping over to chrome to see notes and stuff.

I would love for performers to instead be able to upload tracks to my app, then the sound booth guy could play them straight from chrome. The only catch is that I would like to make sure that those tracks download fully before the show so that the music doesn't cut out mid-show.

My performers are not predictable and don't want a complicated process, I don't want them to all put the tracks on SoundCloud or something. I would like to be able to receive `mp3`, `aif`, or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Downloading the audio

So it looks like this is possible if you put it into the Jquery $(document).ready() function (when the page loads). Original code thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759152/load-a-sound-to-audio-tag-and-play-it-later). More info on this [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313646/how-to-preload-a-sound-in-javascript).

```
// Hide the page until the audio has loaded. 
// You might want to display some kind of preloader graphic 
// while the user waits.
var $body = $('body').css('display', 'none');

$(document).ready(function () {

    var player = new Audio();

    // canplaythrough event is fired when enough of the audio has downloaded
    // to play it through at the current download rate
    player.addEventListener('canplaythrough', audioLoadedHandler);

    function audioLoadedHandler(e) {
        // Audio has loaded, show the page
        $body.css('display', 'block');
        // And start the audio
        player.play(); // Or do whatever now that you have the audio
    }       

    player.src = 'https://example.com/folder/file.wav';
});
```

When the player.src is set, the audio will attempt to be loaded.

So what you will need to do is create an array of players, and array of their source locations (i.e. some audio hosting website/service - *maybe* dropbox if you aren't using anything else) and simply iterate through when the page loads. This way your users could upload to the hosting service manually, or your website could take care of this using an API for the hosting service ([saving to dropbox from js](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver)).

### Keeping track of your audio

Since you will be using multiple files and the user will be uploading more im guessing, it's probably a good idea to keep a list of all of the website source locations for each file (since otherwise you won't know which src locations / file name(s) to load).

One solution to do this would be store your php server side and use a AJAX request to get a global object containing whatever info you need about your audio files, when the webpage loads (before you load the audio).

One example could be:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'server.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"data":"check"},
    success: function(data){

        var audioPlayersMetadata = $.parseJSON(data);

        for(var i = 0; i < audioPlayersMetadata.nPlayers; i++){
          audioPlayers[i].src = audioPlayersMetadata.playerSrc[i];
        }

    }
 });
```

Assuming in your PHP code you created a JSON object with a `nPlayers` parameter, and a `playerSrc` array parameter.

The same would have to be carried out in a similar fasion every time you wanted to load a new audio file, for example. But this time send a request to add to the `playerSrc` array and increment the `nPlayers` by 1.

These are just my suggestions but hopefully it gets you closer to your goal; the downloading audio before playback should be sorted now though!

PS. If it's only one guy using this maybe it's more worthwhile building a compiled app? You could even use [electron,js](https://electronjs.org/) to write it in JS/HTML/CSS, which would let you could store files completely locally.