# No sound in Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Javascript does not play sound in Tampermonkey script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    'use strict';
        var audio = new Audio('https://www.freesound.org/data/previews/256/256458_4772965-lq.mp3');
        audio.play();
        alert('hi!');
})();
```

The script shows alert but does not play sound. Tried both in Chrome and Safari - no sound! At the same time the same code included in HTML file plays sound.

Comment: Try adding a delay to allow you to click before the audio is played.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Your code works for me. Try adding an event listener: [How to preload a sound in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5313646/1287812)